# getting error System.InvalidOperationException: Error deserializing JSON credential data

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to call google cloud vision api from xamarin C# android application code.
I have set environment variable but still I was not able to call api.
So I decided to call it by passing credential json file but now I am getting error deserializing JSON credential data

here is my code

```
string jsonPath = @"C:/Users/abcde/Documents/AndroidApp/My Project-d38b212eadaf.json";

            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonPath);
            var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials());
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);

            var image = Image.FromFile(@"C:/Users/abcde/Documents/AndroidApp/bg.jpg");

            var response = client.DetectLabels(image);

            foreach (var annotation in response)
            {
                if (annotation.Description != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

A path like `C:/Users/abcde/Documents/AndroidApp/My Project-d38b212eadaf.json` is never going to work. This is a Windows filesystem.

Also, you have to start reasoning from the device or emulator. That device cannot just access your Windows filesystem and pick up that file. You will have to get that file on your device somehow and navigate to the right path by using the `Path` object in .NET. Possibly even through a dependency service to get the right paths per platform.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
You are right. I am trying to access this file from android app which is running inside android emulator which is running on windows machine.
I also tried to put this file in Assets folder inside code but still I was not able to access this file.  This might be a silly question but this is my first android app and I am trying to learn file handling and communication with google vision API.

Answer (score 0):

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonPath);
```

is incorrect since [`FromJson`](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/GoogleCredential.cs#L127) expects a JSON string, **not** the path to a JSON file:

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads credential from a string containing JSON credential data.
/// <para>
/// The string can contain a Service Account key file in JSON format from the Google Developers
/// Console or a stored user credential using the format supported by the Cloud SDK.
/// </para>
/// </summary>
public static GoogleCredential FromJson(string json) => defaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromJson(json);
```

*As such, you need to load the contents of the file into a JSON string, and **then** call `FromJson`.*

Comment: I also tried with GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath) but still it is not able to read file.
basically I am struggling to read json file from windows machine into Android app which is running inside emulator.
I have also set the environment variable so that I do not need to feed in the credentials Json file explicitly inside code like I am doing now but environment variable is also not getting me authenticated to call GVision api